# Find out whether two rectangles are intersecting in 3D space

Tags: 3d, intersection, rectangles

I've got two rectangles in 3D space, each given by the coordinates of their 4 corners.
They are not axis aligned, meaning their edges are not necessarily parallel to the world axes. Each rectangle can have any orientation.

Is there an easy way to know whether or not the two rectangles are intersecting?

Comment: Is this programming or math?

Comment: I guess it's both? I'm looking for an algorithm that will allow me to know whether two oriented rectangles (in 3D) are colliding.

Comment: You are right, but maybe you should try with http://math.stackexchange.com?